# Java SQL: Statement.hasResultSet()?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

My app uses MySQL on one platform and SQLite on another, as such there are differences, such as that when using query like `DELETE FROM USERS`:

- On **MySQL**, `PreparedStatement.getResultSet()` will return `null`.
- On **SQLite**, `PreparedStatement.getResultSet()` will throw `java.sql.SQLException: no ResultSet available`.

This may or may not be a bug in SQLite implementation (I think it is supposed to return `null`), but I have to deal with this somehow.

I could use a `try { ... } catch (SQLException e) { ... }` and if the exception message is `"no ResultSet available"`, simply return null manually. This doesn't feel like a right way to do it though.

I could put up an if that makes a check on what JDBC driver is being used and react accordingly, but again, that doesn't feel like a good solution to the problem.

What I would really like is either a method like `.hasResultSet()` that returns a `boolean` *OR* a way to get the SQL command (`SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT` etc) from a statement that has been executed. [I can find neither of the two in SQL API though.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html)

Comment: any specific reason why you want to return null for `DELETE` query because `DELETE` query will always return null as resultset

Comment: i have a method that executes all queries and with a `DELETE` on MySQL it returns null as you said but on SQLite it throws an exception.

Comment: I am using this JDBC driver btw https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Comment: @BhavikShah: that is only true for the two mentioned DBMS. Other DBMS can indeed return something from a DELETE statement, e.g. `delete ... returning ...`)

Comment: No statement has a result set until you execute it. So execute it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When executing a query that returns an unknown amount of results, then you need to use [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29). This method returns a `boolean` indicating the type of result:

- `true`: result is a `ResultSet`
- `false` : result is an update count

If the result is `true`, then you use [`getResultSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet%28%29) to retrieve the `ResultSet`, otherwise [`getUpdateCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount%28%29) to retrieve the update count. If the update count is `-1` it means there are no more results. Note that the update count will also be `-1` when the current result is a `ResultSet`. It is also good to know that `getResultSet()` should return null if there are no more results or if the result is an update count, so the behavior of SQL Lite to throw an exception seems to be wrong.

Now if you want to retrieve more results, you call [`getMoreResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults%28%29) (or its brother accepting an `int` parameter). The `boolean` return value of this method has the same meaning as that of `execute()`, so `false` does not mean there are no more results!

There are only no more results if the `getMoreResults()` returns false **and** `getUpdateCount()` returns `-1` (as also documented in the Javadoc)

Essentially this means that if you want to correctly process all results you need to do something like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(...);
// ...
boolean result = pstmt.execute();
while(true) {
    if (result) {
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
        // Do something with resultset ...
    } else {
        int updateCount = pstmt.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // no more results
            break;
        }
        // Do something with update count ...
    }
    result = pstmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use invalid method to perform delete operation. Instead of using `getResultSet` you should use [`Statement#execute(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)

IMHO the Exeption in SQLite implementation is more valid than null for MySQL. As `delete` do not return the set but a scalar value of delted rows.

Comment: My impression was that you have to use `execute()` anyway even for stuff like `SELECT` before you use a `getResultSet()`? Because for `SELECT` it seems to work fine if I do both...

Comment: Even if I'm wrong in the previous comment my question remains; how do I programatically find out whether to use an `execute()` or a `getResultSet()`?

Comment: @Dreen Use `executeQuery` for queries that produce 1 and only 1 resultset, `executeUpdate` for queries that only modify (and produce a single updatecount) and `execute` for all other things (the existence and amount of update counts and/or resultsets is either unknown in advance or more than 1.

Comment: so I accepted this because I concluded there is no way to determine this programatically. instead, i am going to check for the first word in a query string and use appropriate method as detailed by @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @Dreen There is a way to detect this programmatically, but I don't have time now to type up the full answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for your and everyone else's help anyway, and if you do find the time ill change my accepted answer to yours.