# Expecting multiple ResultSets, but only get one

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets as follows,

```
  create proc test as
  begin
  select '1'
  select a,b into #temp from TABLE1
  select * from #temp
  select '2'
  select 'Done'
  end
```

And my java call is,

```
 CallableStatement stmt = null;
 String procString= "EXEC test";
 stmt = conn.prepareCall(procString);
 boolean results = stmt.execute();
 System.out.println(results);
 do {
      if(results) {
         rs = stmt.getResultSet();
         while (rs.next()) {
          System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + ", " );
         }
         rs.close();
    }
   System.out.println();
   results = stmt.getMoreResults();
   System.out.println("results - "+results);
  } while(results);
```

So as per the above snippet, the output should have all the 4 selects. But I just get the first select and nothing else. I just removed the second select which does insert into temp table, after which I get all the 4 selects.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of the boolean returned by [`getMoreResults`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getMoreResults--):

> There are no more results when the following is true:
>
> ```
> // stmt is a Statement object
> ((stmt.getMoreResults() == false) && (stmt.getUpdateCount() == -1))
> ```
>
> **Returns**:
>      `true` if the next result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` **if it is an update count** or there are no more results

As you haven't got a `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure, the `SELECT ... INTO ...` will generate an update count. This will be returned after the first select. Only when `getMoreResults` returns `false` **and** [`getUpdateCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getUpdateCount--) returns `-1` can you be sure that there are no more results.

Your current code will exit the `do .. while` as soon as `getMoreResults` has returned false. You either need to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your stored procedure, or process multiple results taking into account the update counts.

To correctly process multiple results with update counts you need to do something like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(...);
// ...
boolean result = pstmt.execute();
while(true)
    if (result) {
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
        // Do something with resultset ...
    } else {
        int updateCount = pstmt.getUpdateCount();
        if (updateCount == -1) {
            // no more results
            break;
        }
        // Do something with update count ...
    }
    result = pstmt.getMoreResults();
}
```

I copied the above from my answer to another question, it is similar but not exactly the same. The rest of that answer might provide some more details: [Java SQL: Statement.hasResultSet()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213824/java-sql-statement-hasresultset/14413141#14413141)

Comment: Yep I dint quite notice the fact that the select into will return the updatecount and thats the catch here.. Thanks!